# Finding minimum element in array using Assembly MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly language and I am trying to find the minimum value in an array. This is what I have so far. No matter what I do it jumps to L2 every time even if I change JL to anything else. I must store the minimum in AX. And I must assume that the first item of the array is the minimum and store it in AX. Thanks!

```
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto, dwExitCode:dword

.data

Array WORD 10,2,23,45,21,11
Minimum WORD ?

.code
main proc

mov eax, 0
mov ebx, 0
mov ax,WORD PTR Array
mov Minimum, ax
mov edi,OFFSET Array
L1:
    mov bx, [edi]
    cmp bx, Minimum
    JL L2
    

    L2:
    mov Minimum, bx
    mov ax, Minimum

    add edi,TYPE Array
    loop L1


invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Of course you'll end up at `L2`, since there's nothing after the `JL` that makes execution move anywhere else.

Comment: Move the `L2` label to right before the `add`, and change the `JL` to `JGE`.

Comment: You're not taking advantage of having the minimum in `ax` during the loop.  You could keep it in AX the whole time and only store to the global / static storage when you're done.  (Or not at all if you're doing that to return a value in AX)